# How create return values when mocking Eloquent on Laravel

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-4, phpunit

I am working on a project on Laravel, and I have developed my own version of `User`. I know that Laravel comes with it is own implementation, but just for the sake of the argument, let's forget that.

I am trying to learn how to test in Laravel, and I encountered the following problem:

**Part of the controller**

```
<?php

class UsersController extends BaseController {

    protected $user;

    public function __construct(User $user) {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function login() {

        // Input, Validation, blah, blah blah
        ....

        // Find user
        $users = $this->user->where('email', '=', $email);

        if ($users->count() == 0) {
            // Do something
        } else {
            // Do something else different
        }

        // Lot more stuff...
    }
}
```

Now comes testing. As you see I put the dependency of Eloquent through the constructor so I can mock it. The test are as follow:

```
<?php

class UsertTest extends TestCase {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->userMock = Mockery::mock('Eloquent', 'User');
    }

    public function tearDown() {
        Mockery::close();
    }

    public function testLogin() {

        // Unimportant
        $data = ...

        $this->userMock
            ->shouldReceive('where')
            ->once()
            ->andReturn('foo');

        $this->app->instance('User', $this->userMock);

        // Send the data
        $this->post('/login', $data);
```

When I run the tests, I get this error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function count() on a non-object
```

So it seems that the mock is working, in the sense that the Database is not being hit, but now I am with the problem that I need to mock as well the value returned by the call.

How should I go about it?